# Problema con useState y textarea value. React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, pwa

Estoy desarrollando una web app para hacer la lista del super, cada producto (ProductCard) tiene la opción de agregarle una descripción que ingresa el usuario desde un textarea. Mi problema es que cuando agregas una descripción a un producto se le agrega a todos los demás la misma descripcion. Es decir, el mismo value que ingreso el usuario en el textarea. La idea es cada producto pueda tener su propia descripción o comentario que deja el usuario. https://github.com/franciscominen/supermarket-list-app

```
// MODAL WITH TEXTAREA COMPONENT
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import "./styles.scss"
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import { toast, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
import {listContext} from '../../utils/ListContext';


const ModalComponent = ({item}) => {

  // ADD ITEM AND CONTEXT
    const {addItem, note, noteChange} = useContext(listContext);
    
    const onAdd = () => {
      addItem(item)
    }

  // TOAST NOTIFY ITEM ADD
    const notify = () => toast( `Se agregó ${item.name} a su lista.`, {
      position: "bottom-center",
      autoClose: 1500,
      hideProgressBar: true,
      closeOnClick: false,
      pauseOnHover: true,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
      transition: Slide
    });

  return (
    
    <Popup
      trigger={<button className="button"> <FiEdit style={{color:'#242424', fontSize:'20px'}}/> 
               </button>}
      modal
      nested
    >
      
      {close => (
      
        <Animated animationIn="fadeIn" animationOut="zoomOut"  animationInDuration={300} 
         animationOutDuration={300}>
          <div className="modal">
            
            <div className="header"> 

              <div className='item'>
                <img src={item.img} alt=""/>
                <h2>{item.name} </h2>
              </div>

              <button className="close" onClick={close}>
                <IoCloseOutline />
              </button>

            </div>

            <div className="content">

            // TEXT AREA
              <textarea
                placeholder={window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/productos"
                              ? "Agregue aqui una descripcion sobre este producto"
                              : note }
                value={note}
                onChange={noteChange}
              />        
                
            </div>

            <div className='modal_footer' onClick={notify}>
              { window.location.href === "http://localhost:3000/productos" // MODIFICAR AL HOSTEAR
                ? <button onClick={onAdd}>Agregar a mi lista <BsListCheck/> </button>
                : <button disabled style={{display:'none'}}>Agregar a mi lista <BsListCheck/> </button>
              }
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </Animated>
      )}
      
    </Popup>
  );
}

export default ModalComponent;

// MAP PRODUCTS COMPONENT

import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ProductCard} from '../ProductCardComponent/ProductCard';
import {listContext} from "../../utils/ListContext";

export const ProductList = ({ items }) => {

    const {searchTerm} = useContext(listContext)
    
    return (
        <>
            { items.filter( item => { // SEARCH 
                if (searchTerm == "") {
                    return item
                } else if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
                    return item
                }
            }).map( item => ( 
                
                <ProductCard 
                    key={item.id} 
                    item={item} 
                />

            ))}
        </>
    )
};

PRODCUT CARD COMPONENT
    import React, {useContext} from 'react';
    import "./styles.scss"
    import {RiAddFill} from "react-icons/ri";
    import {listContext} from "../../utils/ListContext";
    import { toast, Slide } from 'react-toastify';
    import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
    import {Animated} from "react-animated-css";
    import ModalComponent from './DescripcionModal';

    export const ProductCard = ({ item }) => {
    
        const {addItem} = useContext(listContext)
    
        const notify = () => toast( `Se agregó ${item.name} a su lista.`, {
            position: "bottom-center",
            autoClose: 1500,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            transition: Slide
            });
    
        const onAdd = () => {
            addItem(item)
        }
    
        return (
    
            <>
                <Animated animationIn="zoomIn" animationOut="fadeOut" isVisible={true} animationInDuration={500} animationInDuration={500} >
                    <div className='card_product' >
    
                        <div className='btns_container'>
    
                            <ModalComponent item={item} />
                            
                            <button onClick={onAdd}>
                                <RiAddFill onClick={notify}/>
                            </button>
    
                        </div>
    
                        <img src={item.img} onerror="this.src='https://ctkbiotech.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/not-available.jpg'"/>
    
                        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
    
                    </div>
                </Animated>
            </>
        )  
    };

// ITEMS IN LIST COMPONENT
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import './styles.scss';
import {listContext} from "../../utils/ListContext";
import {IoCloseOutline} from "react-icons/io5";
import ModalComponent from "../ProductCardComponent/DescripcionModal"

const ItemsInList = () => {

    const { list, removeItem, note } = useContext(listContext);

    return (
        <>
        <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', margin:'20px 0'}}> 

                {list.map(({item}) => {

                    return (
                        <>
                            <section className='listProducts_container'>

                                <div className='list_product' id='listProduct'>

                                    <div className='item_detail'>
                                        <img src={item.img} />
                                        <div className='descipt_container'> 
                                            <h2>{item.name}</h2> 
                                            <p style={{color:'grey', fontSize:'14px'}}>
                                                {note}
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
                                        
                                        <ModalComponent item={item}/>
                                    
                                        <button onClick={()=>{removeItem(item)}}>
                                            <IoCloseOutline style={{marginLeft:'10px'}}/>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    

                                </div>

                            </section>
                        </>
                    )
                })}
        </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default ItemsInList;
```

//CONTEXT COMPONENT

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

export const listContext = createContext();
export const ListProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [list, setList] = useState([]);

    const [note, setNote] = useState(
         localStorage.getItem('note') || ''
        );
     
        useEffect(() => {
            localStorage.setItem('note', note);
        }, [note]);
        
        const handleChange = (e) => {
            setNote(e.target.value)
        }

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

        // Local Storage Get
        useEffect(() => {
            if (localStorage.getItem('list') !== null) {
                setList(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list')));
            }
        }, []);
      
        // Local Storage Set
        useEffect(() => {
            localStorage.setItem('list', JSON.stringify(list));
        }, [list]);

    const isInlist = (id) => {
        const item = list.filter(p => p.item.id === id);
        if ( item.length > 0 ) {
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    }

    function addItem(newItem, quantity) {
        const idx = list.findIndex((listI) => listI.item.id === newItem.id)

        if (idx === -1) {
            const l = [ ...list, { item: newItem, quantity } ]
            setList(l)
        } else {
            const newQuantity = list[idx].quantity + quantity;
            const oldI = list.filter((oldI) => oldI.item.id !== list[idx].item.id)
            const l = [...oldI, { item: list[idx].item, quantity: newQuantity }]
            setList(l)
        }
    }
    
    const removeItem = (item) => {
        const listaNew = list.filter( p => p.item.id != item.id)
        setList(listaNew)
    }
 
    const clearList = () => {
        setList([])
    };

    return (
        <>
            <listContext.Provider value={{
                clearList: clearList,
                addItem: addItem,
                list: list,
                setList: setList,
                searchTerm: searchTerm,
                setSearchTerm: setSearchTerm,
                removeItem: removeItem,
                note: note,
                setNote, setNote,
                handleChange: handleChange
                }}>

                {children}

            </listContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

Adjunto imagen donde esta el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No parece haber relación entre el `item` y su `nota` en `localstorage`, ¿Que has intentado? Saludos

Comment: tu código me hace acordar a cuando no existía la estandarización y escribíamos código spagetti, deberías formatear tu código y subir cada archivo por separado, explicando que es lo que haces